# Using cmake with cuda

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gcc

I try to compile a C++ project that uses opencv and cuda (https://github.com/danielsuo/cuSIFT reset to commit 61d8a2e).
To compile the project I use cmake in the following ways:

## Method 1

```
cmake .. && make -j3 demo
```

This gives me an error message saying

```
error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
```

## Method 2

So I set a different compiler for the build like that

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-5 cmake .. && make -j3 demo
```

which runs a few steps further but returns an error message during the linking step

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable demo
/usr/lib/libtbb.so.2: undefined reference to __cxa_init_primary_exception@CXXABI_1.3.11'
/usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to std::thread::_State::~_State()@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
/usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
/usr/lib/libtbb.so.2: undefined reference to std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::exception_ptr(void*)@CXXABI_1.3.11'
/usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to typeinfo for std::thread::_State@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make:292: demo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:112: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:153: demo] Error 2
```

## Method 3

And when I set the compiler like that

```
cmake .. -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-5 && make -j3 demo
```

I also get an error message

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable demo
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo_generated_cuImage.cu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo_generated_cuSIFT.cu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo_generated_cuSIFT_H.cu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/extras/demo_generated_matching.cu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/extras/demo_generated_rigidTransform.cu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/extras/demo_generated_homography.cu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/extras/demo_generated_math_utils.cu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo_intermediate_link.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `__nv_module_id' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make:292: demo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:112: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:153: demo] Error 2
```

Does somebody know how to compile this project?

Comment: You can use OpenCV's SIFT implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately this implementation is used by a project I am working on and they needed a GPU implementation of SIFT.

Comment: The code compiles fine for me. The test module does not compile because the download address is wrong but the library itself compiles fine.

Comment: Ok I compiled opencv from source and changed gcc from version 7.1 to 5.4. Now it is working too. Thank you for your help.